# Removing keyword from url with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=product%20keyword%20remove
```

I would like to remove, "keyword" from this url using htaccess. This is what I have so far but is not working as expected:

```
RewriteRule ^search=(.*?)keyword(.*?)$ search=$1$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, how should the spaces "%20" be handled? Because at least one of the spaces needs to be removed as well.

There are multiple url that contain "keyword", however the words before and after this keyword might vary, so that's why I tried with (.*)

Thanks

Comment: %20 a space in the url string can be handled by using \s in the regex pattern.

Comment: **what am i doing wrong here?** - you are trying to match against query strings in RewriteRule directive, Query strings can not be handled directly in this directive, you need to use a RewriteCond with %{QUERY_STRING}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*search=[^&]*)%20keyword(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: this works great with just a small mod RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*search=[^&]*)%20keyword(\S*)\sHTTP [NC] , Added in %20 to also remove the space in front of the keyword.

Comment: Yes if you want to remove `%20` as well then indeed it would be: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*search=[^&]*)%20keyword(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

to match against a url with query strings, you can also use %{THE_REQUEST} variable.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} search=(.*?)keyword(.*?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?route=product/search&search=%1%2 [L,R]
```

%n is part of the regex capture group(s) in the RewriteCond

Comment: This works partially, meaning it doesn't catch the part after the keyword, so the url gets rewritten only up to keyword, dropping the last part.

Comment: I tried like this: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} search=(.*?)keyword\S(.*)$ [NC] and the result is search=firstword%252020thirdword%20HTTP/1.0 . So the keyword gets removed, but what is it with the HTTP part being added?

Comment: HTTP 1.0 is the last part of the request string it is being appended because of the greedy behaviour of regex, try adding a ? after the * , **(.*?)** .

Comment: option 1: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} search=(.*?)keyword(.*?)$ [NC] , I still get the HTTP 1.0 part , option 2 : RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} search=(.*?)keyword(.*?) [NC] , I only get the first word, the last part after the keyword is missing.

Comment: @FlorinC. 
Clear your browser cache.

Comment: I have cleared the cache, and I get the same behavior with the two options.

Comment: Remove the  **end of string** char **$** from the RewriteCond pattern.

Comment: Should you not be using `QUERY_STRING` for this?

Comment: Using either THE_REQUEST or QUERY_STRING and removing the end of string char $, results in the url being truncated to just the first word, the one before "keyword".